# Connect Docker Container to Local Elasticsearch service

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, networking

I am running Docker container which runs a jar file inside it.

This jar file need an access to Elasticsearch for reading data and this Elasticsearch service is installed on the local machine (*Not in Docker Container*)

I need to connect to local Elasticsearch service from Docker container to make it work

I wrote ***EXPOSE 9200 9300 service-port*** in Dockerfile and my Docker run command is as follows,

"***docker run -itd  --memory=1g -p 9300:9300 -p 9200:9200  -p service-port:service-port --name service-name service-name -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2 -XshowSettings:vm***"

and when I run this command I get following error,

"***docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint service-name (3de884dd9a62a4a989475721cc4cdf9cb6b78f1a8d345e590471d85052d6a4de): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9300: bind: address already in use.***"

P.S = On my Local server I need to keep elasticsearch service ***ON***

Answer (score 0):

Both the EXPOSE line you quote and the `docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300` options tell Docker that you are running a container that is **providing** an Elasticsearch server, that you want to have **listening** for connections on those ports.
If you’re just trying to make an outbound connection to an Elasticsearch service running somewhere else, you don’t need these options and should remove them.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I did remove "**EXPOSE**" ports except service-port from Dockerfile and made changes in my Docker run command as follows, 

"**docker run -itd -p service-port:service-port --name service-name service-name**" 

and then ran  Dockerfile, It did not give any error and container is up but upon seeing "**Docker logs**" I have encountered an error, "**Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "errorCode**"  Which is an Elasticsearch error so My Docker container failed to establish a connection with local ES service